# iOS: how can I disable calendar alerts?

Tags: ios, calendar

Is it possible to disable alerts coming from the Calendar app? I am talking about the on the screen pop-ups that come before the start of an event. You can turn off the alert sound in the Preferences, but I don't see an option to turn off the alert pop-up.

(My iPhone calendar is synchronized with Google Calendar, and so I already alerts through some other means, and don't want to get them one more time on the iPhone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't disable pop-up reminders globally.
You can turn off an alert by accessing the event properties in the Calendar app, but then 
it will be disabled in Google Agenda too.

Comment: This is what I thought; thank you for confirming this.

Answer (score 6):

Settings > Notifications > Calendar       Here you can select the types of notifications you want for all types of Calendar events, eg you can turn on or off banner pop-ups, sounds, or both, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 8 there's a circled "i" besides calendars that you can click on to manage settings for individual calendars. At the bottom is the toggle for whether to display notification for this calendar.

It is not a global setting but you can toggle it one by one for each calendar, including the Google ones. This should not affect the notification settings you have in the Google Calendar app itself.